# How to use Crosswalk as the browser for inAppBrowser in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm creating an app that needs **webRTC** in order to work. I have the **cordova inappbrowser** and **crosswalk** installed. And I'm using **ionic** for this app.

The problem is that when using **inAppBrowser** its using the *default cordova web view* instead of the more recent *chrome browser* I installed with *crosswalk*. I did some searching and I found this:
[cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-crosswalk](https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-crosswalk)

There's really no documentation and its not available in the plugin repository either so I don't really know how to install it in the app. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The repo you are linking is unfortunately an old fork with no modifications to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is another cordova plugin project on github: 
"This plugin provides a web browser view, which is **using the Crosswalk engine to render pages**."
https://github.com/Shoety/cordova-plugin-inappbrowserxwalk

It is available in the plugin repository and can be installed with cordova:

```
cordova plugin add com.shoety.cordova.plugin.inappbrowserxwalk
```

I haven't tried it out yet but just have the same problem so will probably try it out later and add my experiences.

Comment: This currently doesn't build properly

Comment: Use the pull request from mrjoes to get it to build. One line change.